# Change the URL of nav child entry conditionally

Tags: structure, navigation, children

I want to change the URL of a li from a nav menu conditionally (using a custom field where the user sets the URL), but I don't see how to use conditionals with `{% ifchildren %}`?

```
{% nav entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

        {% if entry.id in craft.entries.descendantOf(4).ids() %}
            **change the url of all child entries**
        {% endif %}

        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul class="menu sub-items">
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

ID 4's children is the entry which I want to display custom URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `{% ifchildren %}` use `{% if entry.hasDescendants %}`. It allows for more flexibility in your nav templating.